# Why additional user on Ubuntu uses my $NVM_DIR?

Tags: nvm

I installed `nvm` as recomended in [docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
```

Next, I added additional user `node-user` on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo useradd -m node-user
```

Where flag `-m` meaning "with home directory".

But when I trying login via terminal under this user:

```
sudo -u node-user -s
```

I have warn:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               npm update check failed                │
│         Try running with sudo or get access          │
│         to the local update config store via         │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/me/.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Where `me` it's my user name. And if I to do:

```
node-user@host:~$ echo $NVM_DIR
> /home/me/.config
```

So, why additional user uses my `$NVM_DIR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1195250/480169), @steeldriver point me to [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10/1187000#1187000).

All works fine when I created system user and login in shell like this:

```
sudo -H -u node-user -s
```

So flag `-H` resolved my problem.